# How to pass an array as function argument?

Tags: bash

Struggling for a while passing an array as argument but it's not working anyway. I've tried like below:

```
#! /bin/bash

function copyFiles{
   arr="$1"
   for i in "${arr[@]}";
      do
          echo "$i"
      done

}

array=("one" "two" "three")

copyFiles $array
```

An answer with explanation would be nice.

Edit: Basically, i will eventually call the function from another script file. Plz explain the constraints if possible.

Comment: See also [this question for regular "indexed" bash arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063347/4561887) and [this question for associative bash arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4069188/4561887). I've written [a brand-new answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060036/4561887) which shows a really easy way to pass either type of array _by reference_ in bash. I have links there to other answers which show how to _manually serialize and deserialize both types of arrays_ as well ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855715/4561887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060913/4561887)).

Answer (score 234, accepted):

- Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element, use

  ```
  copyFiles "${array[@]}"
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  copyFiles $array
  ```
- Use a she-bang

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```
- Use the correct function syntax

  Valid variants are

  ```
  function copyFiles {…}
  function copyFiles(){…}
  function copyFiles() {…}
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  function copyFiles{…}
  ```
- Use the right syntax to get the array parameter

  ```
  arr=("$@")
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  arr="$1"
  ```

---

Therefore

```
#!/bin/bash
function copyFiles() {
   arr=("$@")
   for i in "${arr[@]}";
      do
          echo "$i"
      done

}

array=("one 1" "two 2" "three 3")

copyFiles "${array[@]}"
```

Output is (my script has the name `foo`)

```
$ ./foo   
one 1
two 2
three 3
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't    function copyFiles{…}  a correct syntax? Though i am a new bie i run some program successfully with the syntax.

Comment: Valid variants are `copyFiles {…}` and `copyFiles(){…}` and `copyFiles() {…}`, but not `copyFiles{…}`. Note the space in the variant without `()`

Comment: among the variants, there's `copyFiles() { ... }` without a `function` keyword. Added benefit : also valid in POSIX (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo)

Comment: In this particular case you can do `for i; do ...; done` to iterate over `$@`. Also, this wasn't asked, but if you need to pass a couple of arrays, you probably want to [pass by reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/674366/186999).

Comment: Shebang is spelled without the dash.

Comment: Is there a critical difference between `#! /bin/bash` and `#!/bin/bash`? I have read many tutorials using the former - it works in peace. Now here the latter indicated how the correct syntax.

Comment: This does not handle arguments that are empty strings. It just expands the array as arguments and recreates it.

Answer (score 110):

If you want to pass one or more arguments AND an array, I propose this change to the script of @A.B.
Array should be the ***last*** argument and ***only one*** array can be passed

```
#!/bin/bash
function copyFiles() {
   local msg="$1"   # Save first argument in a variable
   shift            # Shift all arguments to the left (original $1 gets lost)
   local arr=("$@") # Rebuild the array with rest of arguments
   for i in "${arr[@]}";
      do
          echo "$msg $i"
      done
}

array=("one" "two" "three")

copyFiles "Copying" "${array[@]}"
```

Output:

```
$ ./foo   
Copying one
Copying two
Copying three
```

Comment: +1 for learning about an array needing to be at the end and that only one should be sent

Comment: It's also useful to use shift's argument sometimes, so if you had 6 arguments before the array, you can use `shift 6`.

Comment: You convert "the rest of arguments" into `arr`. Is it possible to have an array parameter in the middle? Or even several arrays parameters? `function copyAndMove() { msg1=$1 ; arr1=...?... ; msg2=? ; arr2=...?... ; msg3=? ; ... }`. Like I would define it in python: `def copyAndMove(msg1="foo", cpFiles=[], msg2="bar", mvFiles=[], msg3="baz"): ...`. Never mind, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/4017175/472245

Comment: Explained really well. and didn't know about shift. Thanks.

Comment: You can also achieve same behavior without using `shift` by doing this:
`local msg="$1"; local -a arr=( "${@:2}" )`

Comment: You can actually manually pass any number of bash arrays or bash associative arrays, with many arguments, and in any location within the arguments, as I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855715/4561887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060913/4561887). Furthermore, bash arrays can even be passed _by reference_ now, which is much easier, as I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060036/4561887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060913/4561887).

Answer (score 47):

You could also pass the array as a reference. i.e.:

```
#!/bin/bash

function copyFiles {
   local -n arr=$1

   for i in "${arr[@]}"
   do
      echo "$i"
   done
}

array=("one" "two" "three")

copyFiles array
```

but note that any modifications to arr will be made to array.

Comment: Though, it wasn't exactly what i want, but it still nice to know how pass by reference work in bash.  +1 :)

Comment: Requires bash 4.3+

Comment: @user448115 Yes, but what if the input array is not ever supposed to be changed by the function in question. In effect, what if the passing of an array is only being done to get a result. Exposing your inputs to potentially unexpected data mutations is not wise.

Comment: Bash is not Haskell. You've got to compromise. On a different note, it makes sense to do `[ "$1" = arr ] || local -n arr=$1` in place of just `local -n arr=$1`. That way the argument and the parameter names can coincide. As far as I can tell, the scope in `bash` is dynamic.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick why would an array named `n` be a circular reference? If you changed the name `array` to `n` and called the function e.g. `copyFiles n` then inside the function the local variable `arr` is created _effectively_ as an alias or synonym of `n`. `local -n arr` also means a locally (function) scoped variable so even if you called that `n` as well it wouldn't be circular. The fact that changing the `arr` inside the function also changes the value of `array` outside the function is not circular either, it's because both names ultimately point to values in the same address space.

Comment: EDIT: I see what you mean; second part of what I said is incorrect. I tried changing the local `arr` to `n` as well and it does echo a warning about circular name reference - but it doesn't error, it still runs. x-yuri's suggestion deals with that warning nicely.

Comment: This is quite helpful.  I wonder, though, about the statement in man bash-builtins (for the declare -n option, which local incorporates): "The -n attribute cannot be applied to array variables."  I don't know enough yet to know what to make of this statement in light of this answer.  Can someone comment?

Answer (score 13):

There are couple of problems. Here is the working form :

```
#!/bin/bash
function copyFiles {
   arr=( "$@" )
   for i in "${arr[@]}";
      do
          echo "$i"
      done

}

array=("one" "two" "three")
copyFiles "${array[@]}"
```

- There need to be at least a space between function declaration and `{`
- You can not use `$array`, as `array` is an array not a variable. If you want to get all the values of an array use `"${array[@]}"`
- In you main function declaration you need `arr="$@"` as `"${array[@]}"` will expand to the indexed values separated by spaces, if you use `$1` you would get only the first value. To get all the values use `arr="${arr[@]}"`.

Comment: You need `arr=("$@")`

Comment: To see the difference, add a `break` below `echo "$i"`. In your version you will still see all the elements. However, it should be three lines.

Comment: @heemayl: small typo --  The { in your array of the second bullet went missing ... "${array[@]}" ...

Comment: At the very end of the last bullet point is there also a missing `{`, or is this intentional `arr="$arr[@]}"` ?

Comment: @Davos Typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Here follows a slightly larger example. For explanation, see the comments in the code.

```
#!/bin/bash -u
# ==============================================================================
# Description
# -----------
# Show the content of an array by displaying each element separated by a
# vertical bar (|).
#
# Arg Description
# --- -----------
# 1   The array
# ==============================================================================
show_array()
{
    declare -a arr=("${@}")
    declare -i len=${#arr[@]}
    # Show passed array
    for ((n = 0; n < len; n++))
    do
        echo -en "|${arr[$n]}"
    done
    echo "|"
}

# ==============================================================================
# Description
# -----------
# This function takes two arrays as arguments together with their sizes and a
# name of an array which should be created and returned from this function.
#
# Arg Description
# --- -----------
# 1   Length of first array
# 2   First array
# 3   Length of second array
# 4   Second array
# 5   Name of returned array
# ==============================================================================
array_demo()
{
    declare -a argv=("${@}")                           # All arguments in one big array
    declare -i len_1=${argv[0]}                        # Length of first array passad
    declare -a arr_1=("${argv[@]:1:$len_1}")           # First array
    declare -i len_2=${argv[(len_1 + 1)]}              # Length of second array passad
    declare -a arr_2=("${argv[@]:(len_1 + 2):$len_2}") # Second array
    declare -i totlen=${#argv[@]}                      # Length of argv array (len_1+len_2+2)
    declare __ret_array_name=${argv[(totlen - 1)]}     # Name of array to be returned

    # Show passed arrays
    echo -en "Array 1: "; show_array "${arr_1[@]}"
    echo -en "Array 2: "; show_array "${arr_2[@]}"

    # Create array to be returned with given name (by concatenating passed arrays in opposite order)
    eval ${__ret_array_name}='("${arr_2[@]}" "${arr_1[@]}")'
}

########################
##### Demo program #####
########################
declare -a array_1=(Only 1 word @ the time)                                       # 6 elements
declare -a array_2=("Space separated words," sometimes using "string paretheses") # 4 elements
declare -a my_out # Will contain output from array_demo()

# A: Length of array_1
# B: First array, not necessary with string parentheses here
# C: Length of array_2
# D: Second array, necessary with string parentheses here
# E: Name of array that should be returned from function.
#          A              B             C              D               E
array_demo ${#array_1[@]} ${array_1[@]} ${#array_2[@]} "${array_2[@]}" my_out

# Show that array_demo really returned specified array in my_out:
echo -en "Returns: "; show_array "${my_out[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

As ugly as it is, here is a workaround that works as long as you aren't passing an array explicitly, but a variable corresponding to an array:

```
function passarray()
{
    eval array_internally=("$(echo '${'$1'[@]}')")
    # access array now via array_internally
    echo "${array_internally[@]}"
    #...
}

array=(0 1 2 3 4 5)
passarray array # echo's (0 1 2 3 4 5) as expected
```

I'm sure someone can come up with a cleaner implementation of the idea, but I've found this to be a better solution than passing an array as `"{array[@]"}` and then accessing it internally using `array_inside=("$@")`. This becomes complicated when there are other positional/`getopts` parameters. In these cases, I've had to first determine and then remove the parameters not associated with the array using some combination of `shift` and array element removal.

A purist perspective likely views this approach as a violation of the language, but pragmatically speaking, this approach has saved me a whole lot of grief. On a related topic, I also use `eval` to assign an internally constructed array to a variable named according to a parameter `target_varname` I pass to the function:

```
eval $target_varname=$"(${array_inside[@]})"
```

Comment: That is ugly and unncessary. If you want to pass the array by name, make `array_internally` an alias of it: `declare -n  array_internally=$1`. And the rest of it about "becomes complicated" and "determine  and then remove ..." applies to irrespective of how you pass the array, so I don't see what's the point of that. And `eval`ing an array potentially containing special characters is just waiting for grief to happen at a later date.

Comment: Just posted a proposition : pass one or multiple strings and make them an array inside the function.

Comment: @muru, what do you make of the statement in man bash-builtins (for the declare -n option, which local incorporates): "The -n attribute cannot be applied to array variables."  I don't know enough yet to understand how this fits, except to know that absent other input such as your suggestion, the statement would, in my ignorance, discourage me from using the -n option in this situation.

Comment: @ebsf I believe what it means is that you can't have something like `declare -an foo=(...)` where a variable is both an array and a nameref. Having an array `foo` and then doing `declare -n bar=foo` has worked fine for years, e.g., [another answer from 7 years ago on this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/674366/158442), or [this answer from me on U&L from 5 years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412919/70524)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to pass as position arguments. Nothing else. You may pass as string, but this way may cause some troubles. Example:

```
array=(one two three four five)

function show_passed_array(){
  echo $@
}
```

or

```
function show_passed_array(){
  while $# -gt 0;do
    echo $1;shift
  done
}

    show_passed_array ${array[@]}
```

output:

```
  one two three four five
```

You mean if array value has space symbols you must quote elements first before pass for accessing value by index in function use  $1 $2 $3 ... position parameters. Where index 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2,... To iterate access it is best to use always $1 and after Shift. Nothing additional is needed. You may pass arguments without any array like this:

```
show_passed_array one two three four five
```

bash media automatically builds an array from passed arguments that passed them to function and then you have position arguments.
Furthermore when you write ${array[2]} you really write consequent argument one two three four and passed them to the function.
So those calls are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to avoid any limitation about "passing array(s) args" to a function by... passing strings, and make them array INSIDE the function :

```
#!/bin/bash

false_array1='1 2 3 4 5'
false_array2='my super fake array to deceive my function'
my_normal_string='John'

function i_love_arrays(){
  local myNumbers=("$1")
  local mySentence=("$2")
  local myName="$3"
  echo "My favorite numbers are, for sure: "
  for number in ${myNumbers[@]}
  do
    echo $number
  done
  echo "Let's make an ugly split of a sentence: "
  for word in ${mySentence[@]}
  do
    echo $word
  done
  echo "Yeah, I know, glad to meet you too. I'm ${myName}."
}

i_love_arrays "${false_array1}" "${false_array2}" "${my_normal_string}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using references (easiest way; best and only way for passing **associative arrays**):

```bsh
print()
{
    [ "$1" = "arr" ] || { declare -n arr; arr="$1"; }
    # The name of reference mustn't match the input coming to the function.
    # If it does, use the name directly as array instead of reference.
    
    echo "${arr[@]}"
}

print arr
```

For normal (**non-associative**) arrays:

Here is a function that copies the passed array in new (local) array for usage. Can be time-taking for long arrays.

```bsh
copy_fn()
{
    eval local newarr=\(\${$1[@]}\)
    echo ${newarr[@]}
}
```

Further, like in C++ you can only pass an array pointer, but in python, as a shared variable which you can modify as well.

Here is the shared variables approach.. useful for long arrays.

```
modify_arr()
{
    eval local ptr=$1        # works as if ptr is a pointer to actual "array-name" (arr)  # the original array is, thus, still same, not a copy
    eval $ptr+=(1)           # modify the array
    echo ${ptr[@]}           # will print name of the array (arr)
    eval echo \$\{$ptr[@]\}  # will print the actual array (arr)
}

modify_arr a
echo ${a[@]}
```

-*Himanshu*

Comment: What I like about your answer is the `[ "$1" = arr ] || local -n arr=$1` part. The rest... I don't think you put enough effort for it to be readable. Also, your examples lack quoting. And I doubt the rest of the ideas are practical.

Comment: Thanks for  feedback. I'll consider improvements in my further answers. I put too much unnecessary effort in explaining everything I guess.

Answer (score 0):

@SBF

Your idea sparked some thinking on a situation I needed where two arrays were to be compared.

You can pass multiple arrays using your technique with a minor modification.  See below

Thank you!

(works in bash 3.3 on Debian)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
function TakeTwoArrays() {
    local Var1="$1"
    local Var2="$2"
    local NumArray1="$3"
    local NumArray2="$4"
    shift 4
    local -a AllArray=("$@")
    local -a Array1="${AllArray[@]:0:${NumArray1}}"
    local -a Array2="${AllArray[@]:${NumArray1}}"

    echo "Var1 is ${Var1}"
    echo "Var2 is ${Var2}"
    echo "Array1 has ${NumArray1} entries:"
    printf '%s\n' "${Array1[@]}"
    echo "Array2 has ${NumArray2} entries:"
    printf '%s\n' "${Array2[@]}"
}
FirstArg="So Far"
SecondArg="So Good"
Array1Arg=("But" "the" "real" "question" "is")
NumArray1Arg="${#Array1Arg[@]}"
Array2Arg=("What" "happens" "with" "the" "second" "set" "of" "elements")
NumArray2Arg="${#Array2Arg[@]}"
TakeTwoArrays "${FirstArg}" "${SecondArg}" "${NumArray1Arg}" "${NumArray2Arg}" "${Array1Arg[@]}" "${Array2Arg[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot pass arguments to a function in Bash. Arrays are not really first class objects and all of the solutions above just end up being workarounds with lots of leaky abstractions.

The key issue you will find is that the array is expanded and all indexes are lost when passed. So for instance, having an array with empty strings is not possible to pass into another function: they will all be lost on expansion.

There are workaround, like adding separators, and this [Unix Stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690672/18594) has some more background, but essentially the answer is that Bash does not support it directly.